React-native app BUILD FAIL using jenkins pipline ERROR: :app:generateAutolinkingPackageList FAILED
I recently started using Jenkins, and my first attempt was to build a React Native app and upload it to the GitHub releases. I guess I set up all the required plugins and environments, but when I tried to build React Native, I ran into a problem.
Console Output:
Replayed #1

Obtained Jenkinsfile from e6ecb5376d67442b7f6e093ac53b2c5a531db40d
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins
 in /Users/niranjanshk/.jenkins/workspace/asdfhjkl
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Checkout SCM)
[Pipeline] checkout
The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential Github
 > git rev-parse --resolve-git-dir /Users/niranjanshk/.jenkins/workspace/asdfhjkl/.git # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/niranjanshk27/asdfghj.git # timeout=10
Fetching without tags
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/niranjanshk27/asdfghj.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.39.5 (Apple Git-154)'
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials Access to github
 > git fetch --no-tags --force --progress -- https://github.com/niranjanshk27/asdfghj.git +refs/heads/main:refs/remotes/origin/main # timeout=10
Checking out Revision e6ecb5376d67442b7f6e093ac53b2c5a531db40d (main)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f e6ecb5376d67442b7f6e093ac53b2c5a531db40d # timeout=10
Commit message: "update setting"
 > git rev-list --no-walk e6ecb5376d67442b7f6e093ac53b2c5a531db40d # timeout=10
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Prepare)
[Pipeline] echo
Preparing the application
[Pipeline] nodejs
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ pwd
/Users/niranjanshk/.jenkins/workspace/asdfghjkl
+ yarn install --frozen-lockfile
yarn install v1.22.19
[1/5] Validating package.json...
[2/5] Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
$ patch-package
patch-package 8.0.0
Applying patches...
react-native-snap-carousel@3.9.1 ✔
Done in 1.09s.
++ node -p 'require('\''./package.json'\'').version'
+ appVersion=0.0.1
+ APP_VERSION=0.0.1
+ RELEASE_VERSION=v0.0.1
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // nodejs
[Pipeline] sh
+ pwd
/Users/niranjanshk/.jenkins/workspace/asdfghjkl
+ cd android
+ pwd
/Users/niranjanshk/.jenkins/workspace/asdfghjkl/android
+ ./gradlew clean
> Task :gradle-plugin:settings-plugin:checkKotlinGradlePluginConfigurationErrors
> Task :gradle-plugin:shared:checkKotlinGradlePluginConfigurationErrors
> Task :gradle-plugin:shared:compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:shared:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :gradle-plugin:shared:processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :gradle-plugin:shared:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:shared:jar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:settings-plugin:compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:settings-plugin:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :gradle-plugin:settings-plugin:pluginDescriptors UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:settings-plugin:processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:settings-plugin:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:settings-plugin:jar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:react-native-gradle-plugin:checkKotlinGradlePluginConfigurationErrors
> Task :gradle-plugin:react-native-gradle-plugin:pluginDescriptors
> Task :gradle-plugin:react-native-gradle-plugin:processResources
> Task :gradle-plugin:react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin
> Task :gradle-plugin:react-native-gradle-plugin:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :gradle-plugin:react-native-gradle-plugin:classes
> Task :gradle-plugin:react-native-gradle-plugin:jar
> Task :app:clean UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 4s
14 actionable tasks: 7 executed, 7 up-to-date
+ ./gradlew assembleRelease
> Task :gradle-plugin:settings-plugin:checkKotlinGradlePluginConfigurationErrors
> Task :gradle-plugin:shared:checkKotlinGradlePluginConfigurationErrors
> Task :gradle-plugin:shared:compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:shared:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :gradle-plugin:shared:processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :gradle-plugin:shared:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:shared:jar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:settings-plugin:compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:settings-plugin:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :gradle-plugin:settings-plugin:pluginDescriptors UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:settings-plugin:processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:settings-plugin:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:settings-plugin:jar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:react-native-gradle-plugin:checkKotlinGradlePluginConfigurationErrors
> Task :gradle-plugin:react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:react-native-gradle-plugin:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :gradle-plugin:react-native-gradle-plugin:pluginDescriptors UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:react-native-gradle-plugin:processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:react-native-gradle-plugin:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:react-native-gradle-plugin:jar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:buildKotlinToolingMetadata
> Task :app:checkKotlinGradlePluginConfigurationErrors
> Task :app:generateAutolinkingPackageList FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:generateAutolinkingPackageList'.
> RNGP - Autolinking: Could not find project.android.packageName in react-native config output! Could not autolink packages without this field.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 1s
16 actionable tasks: 6 executed, 10 up-to-date
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Build)
Stage "Build" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] getContext
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Deploy)
Stage "Deploy" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] getContext
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Post Actions)
[Pipeline] echo
Always
[Pipeline] cleanWs
[WS-CLEANUP] Deleting project workspace...
[WS-CLEANUP] Deferred wipeout is disabled by the job configuration...
[WS-CLEANUP] done
[Pipeline] echo
Fail
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1

GitHub has been notified of this commit’s build result

Finished: FAILURE

Setting.gradle
pluginManagement { includeBuild("../node_modules/@react-native/gradle-plugin") }
plugins { id("com.facebook.react.settings") }
extensions.configure(com.facebook.react.ReactSettingsExtension){ ex -> ex.autolinkLibrariesFromCommand() }
rootProject.name = 'moviesApp'
include ':app'
includeBuild('../node_modules/@react-native/gradle-plugin')

I have downgraded the Gradel version but ran into the same problem. I'm guessing Jenkins does not know the location of react-native-cli. Could someone guide me how to fix this
Details:
Gradel version 8.7
react-native 0.75.2
